# C# Windows Media Player how to Delete a Playist (WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist)

Tags: c#, windows, playlist, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm trying to delete a WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist in C#
I've already tried it with these methods

```
WMP.playlistCollection.remove(playlist);
WMP.playlistCollection.setDeleted(playlist, true);
```

as well as this code from a similar question:

```
IWMPPlaylistArray plCollection = WMP.playlistCollection.getByName("myplaylist");
if (plCollection.count > 0)
{
    IWMPPlaylist pl = plCollection.Item(0);
    WMP.playlistCollection.remove(pl);
}
```

but I didn't get it to work. The playist is the current playlist of the windows media player.
I hope you guys can help me out.